# each item wise count

Tags: oracle

I have 2 columns job and department in the table emp.

```
job                              department
-------------------------------------------
manager                          accounting
president            accounting
manager              accounting
clerk                accounting
manager              accounting
manager              accounting
manager              accounting
clerk                accounting
analyst              accounting
security             accounting
security             accounting
clerk                accounting
analyst                          accounting
security                         accounting
```

I have a requirement to pull the data like below

```
status       status_numbers        status           status_numbers
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total               14             Total                                  14
manager             5              manager                                 5
president       1              president                       1
clerk           3              clerk                   3
analyst         2              analyst                 2
security            3              security                3
```

here status and status_numbers columns needs to be repeated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `rollup` to do this:

```
select coalesce(job, 'Total') status, count(*) status_numbers,
       coalesce(job, 'Total') status2, count(*) status_numbers2
  from jobs
 group by rollup(job)
 order by grouping_id(job) desc;
```

example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8d825/1

Comment: how to include deptno in the above query for joining dept table?

Comment: @ravt just add it to the select + group by. eg http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/77780/1. if shown two options there, one with a grand total on dept + job and one without as you didn't say how you wanted the output to look like.